# How to simply pass a variable use $_session and Ajax query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm tring to hide a file using $_session and AJAX, but the variable never show in the last session, here is the files

ajax.php

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var value = $('#valor').val()

    $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "salvar.php", 
                data: {valor: value},
                success: function(response) { 
                  console.log(response);

                }
            }); 
});
```

salvar.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
  $_SESSION['valor'] = $_POST['valor']; 
?>
```

query.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php  

if (isset($_SESSION['valor'])) echo 'si';
else ('nop');
?>
```

If I put an echo in the "salvar file" the AJAX response, but I need to the variable is print in the query file

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code is fine, I've checked with everything you wrote and I get "si"

Comment: Hi, tnks but in my server no work i dont recibe anything

Comment: Please check your logs/http requests for errors. Also according to your post you put Javascript in a php file. I guess this is a typo?